# Encoding byte array to Hex string

Tags: java, arrays, encoding, hex

I have come across a legacy piece of code encoding byte array to hex string which is in production and have never caused an issue.

This piece of code is used as:

- We encrypt a user password. The encryptor returns a `byte[]`.
- We convert the `byte[]` to Hex String using this encoder code and then use that `String` representation in our properties file and so on.

However, yesterday we have hit a password, whose encrypted `byte[]` version is getting encoded incorrectly.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class ByteArrayToHexEncoder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DecoderException {
        String hexString = "a0d21588c0a2c2fc68dc859197fc78cd"; // correct hex representation
        // equivalent byte array: this is the byte array returned by the encryptor
        byte[] byteArray = Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray());

        // legacy encoder
        System.out.println("Legacy code encodes as: " + encodeHexBytesWithPadding(byteArray));

        // commons-codec encoder
        System.out.println("Commons codec encode as: " + new String(Hex.encodeHex(byteArray)));
    }

    private static final String PADDING_ZEROS =
            "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

    private static final HashMap<Integer, Character> MAP_OF_HEX = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(0, '0');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(1, '1');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(2, '2');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(3, '3');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(4, '4');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(5, '5');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(6, '6');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(7, '7');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(8, '8');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(9, '9');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(10, 'a');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(11, 'b');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(12, 'c');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(13, 'd');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(14, 'e');
        MAP_OF_HEX.put(15, 'f');
    }

    public static String encodeHexBytesWithPadding(byte[] inputByteArray) {
        String encodedValue = encodeHexBytes(inputByteArray);
        int expectedSize = inputByteArray.length * 2;
        if (encodedValue.length() < expectedSize) {
            int zerosToPad = expectedSize - encodedValue.length();
            encodedValue = PADDING_ZEROS.substring(0, zerosToPad) + encodedValue;
        }
        return encodedValue;
    }

    public static String encodeHexBytes(byte[] inputByteArray) {
        String encodedValue;
        if (inputByteArray[0] < 0) {
            // Something is wrong here! Don't know what!
            byte oldValue = inputByteArray[0];
            inputByteArray[0] = (byte) (oldValue & 0x0F);
            int nibble = (oldValue >> 4) & 0x0F;
            encodedValue = new BigInteger(inputByteArray).toString(16);
            inputByteArray[0] = oldValue;
            encodedValue = MAP_OF_HEX.get(nibble) + encodedValue;
        } else {
            encodedValue = new BigInteger(inputByteArray).toString(16);
        }
        return encodedValue;
    }
}
```

The legacy code outputs the encoded value as: `0ad21588c0a2c2fc68dc859197fc78cd` while the correct expected value should be: `a0d21588c0a2c2fc68dc859197fc78cd`.

I am trying to understand what's wrong with the encoder and need some help understanding.

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger(byte[])` constructor is there to handle [two's complement representation of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) where the most significant bit also denotes the sign. The `Hex` common-codec simply translates each byte into a hex representation, there is no special meaning to the most significant bit.

Your legacy code in the `if (inputByteArray[0] < 0)` branch attempts to modify the first byte in the `byte[]` input probably to work around the representation of negative numbers in the two-complement's form e.g. `-1` being represented as `ff`. Unfortunately this is implemented incorrectly in your legacy code:

```
String input = "a000000001";
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(input.toCharArray());
System.out.println(encodeHexBytesWithPadding(bytes));
System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(bytes));
```

will print

```
00000000a1
a000000001
```

showing that the legacy code values are completely wrong.

There is not much to salvage here IMO, instead use `Hex.encodeHexString()` instead or check [other options discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java).

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more.. If modifying the first byte to ignore the sign of the 2-complement form wrong ?